# Issue in sorting Email Values, using AngularJS custom sort function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a column in which i am displaying Email of user, i have added sort functionality to it. But the resultant array is not sorted properly.

[Sample code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/zjvsu/895/)

Any help will be appreciated

```
<ul ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:'email':false">
```

In the example code, output of sorting [Ascending] is

> abc+1@abc.com
>   abc@abc.com
>   bac@abc.com

But Expected output is

> abc@abc.com
>   abc+1@abc.com
>   bac@abc.com

Comment: Please place all relevant code in the question and provide expected results. What does `not sorted properly` mean? Demo seems to work

Comment: The sorting is quite proper in your code . its sorting alphabetically

Comment: `['bac@abc.com','abc@abc.com','abc+1@abc.com'].sort()`produces same order. Has nothing to do with angular itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is to use a custom sort function and to "cut" the E-Mail at the `@` symbol. Otherwise the whole string is going to be compared and `@` is higher in value than `+`.

If you only want to match the `Usernames` you should be fine. Otherwise you need to also compare the domains, before comparing `Usernames`.

Here is a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zjvsu/898/

Comment: I edited your answer to include the JS fiddle link. :-)

Comment: Thanks for Feedback and Editing ;) I'm happy that i could help :)